# How to split up a nav bar and change links depending on a condition

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to have two central links in my horizontal navigation bar at the top of my web page and two links in the right, that will be different depending on if a user is logged in so far.

My code so far:

```
<div class="topnav">
    <nav>   
            <li><a href="Leaderboard.php">Leaderboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="Competition.php">Competition</a></li>
            <?php 

                if(isset($_SESSION["name"])) {
                     echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>Profile page</a></li>" ;
                     echo "<li><a href='includes/logout.inc.php'>Log out page</a></li>";    
                    }
                else {
                    echo "<li><a href='signup.php'>Sign Up</a></li>";
                    echo "<li><a href='login.php'> log In</a></li>";                    
                    }                   
            ?> 
        </ul> 
    </nav>      
</div>
```

My CSS code so far:

```
body {
  background-color: #7FA9FF;;
}


li {
    float: right;

}
```

The links change as they should but it is all one class so the stay together when I move them using css. e.g float right.

I have tried changing the php section into another class but no joy.

I'm open to any ideas on how to get this to work.

Below is what I am trying to achieve

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
                                 link1 link2                         link3 link4
```

Comment: What do you mean "when I move them"?
I don't know if the problem is related to this, but I see there is a `</ul>` without its corresponding `<ul>`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mean when I use css to move my menu around. All the links stay together - which is expected as they are all one call.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your issue with the limited information. I think it would be helpful if you showed a screen shot of what it currently looks like with a detailed explanation of what it should look like. We don't know what you mean by "move my menu around" and what "links stay together" really mean. You should also post your CSS, since that seem to be what you're struggling with. All we see from the code is that you present different links, not different layouts. Remember that we don't know anything about your application, or your vision, at all.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? As you say, the behavior you are experiencing is the expected one.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Apologies. So I have a vertical navigation bar across the top of my web page. I want to center two links to other pages in the middle and then two other links (in my php code) in the far right of the navigational bar. My css has very little in at the moment but I will edit the question with it included.

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on css's [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It makes it much easier to handle these kinds of things.

Comment: Thank you for that link it's really helpful! I have played with flexbox before but didn't realize you can split up items in your container like that!